# Arduino dealing with multiple pins

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm new at arduino, Here is a problem in inputting data from multiple pins and writing in to other pins, The input comes from transmitter's reciever and it writes data to KK board pins.The code is simple however when it takes an input from one pin the other pin is disabled and the button is not working. Here is the code:

```
Servo ale, ele;
Void setup()
{
ale.attach(11);
ele.attach(12);
........
.....
}
Void loop()
{
a = pulseIn(6, HIGH, 20000);
b = pulseIn(7, HIGH, 20000);
ale.writeMicroseconds(a);
ele.writeMicroseconds(b);
..........
......
}
```

Is there something that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`pulseIn`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn) function waits for the pin to go high, than waits for the pin to go low and only then it returns and the execution of the program continues for the next line.

If you want to be able to receive input from several pins concurrently, you need to simulate `pulseIn` behavior over several cycles of `loop` function.

There are two options (simplified pseudo code):

1. For each pin separately, every loop cycle you read pin value, if it is transitioning from low to high, a flag a set and you save the current `millis`. When it goes low again, you measure the current `millis` and subtract the previous reading. This will give you the `a` or `b`.
2. Same as `1` but instead of checking every `loop` cycle, you can [attach interrupts](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) for low to high and high to low transitions.